# What does veda have to say about yoga-marga?

Tags: vedas, yoga

**I would Like to mention/recommend that If you are a vedagya-वेदज्ञ(A person who studied vedic samhitas and now knows about everything written in them)then only answer my question**.

I was reading [Shiva-Samhita](http://nitayoga.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Yoga-Shiva-Samhita.pdf), and when I read from verse-4 to verse-16 I  was awestruck because it described exactly what's in a mind of reader when he reads text (i.e. he/reader wants physical/working attainment of goals not just empty philosophical thoughts).

I think Philosophies are only good when applied in real world and realized that is what yoga do. Yoga unites you with your true-self, so I am not offending any one who just believes in philosophies.

I also include bhakti-marga in my list because without knowing the first step you cannot think of reaching the goal of self realization which is bhakti. Also bhakti is too far because first we need to discipline our body then comes discipline of mind.

Is there any mentioning/praising of yoga-marga/yogic path in vedas?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Bhakti Yoga is a type of Yoga.  Are you asking about Karma Yoga, the path of action?

Comment: I am asking about the yogic marga, the asthanga-yoga.

Comment: Good question sir. Yoga =  Practice practice practice. Remember an airplane. An airplane, even though it has to fly on the sky, it starts by running around the runway, then using that momentum it flies up above and beyond the land. Similarly one must begin practicing the philosophy of Vedanta (or Yoga or anything else) and eventually the momentum gathered will be so great that it lifts one up and above all philosophies. All philosophies become One and Same upon Realization. What realization is that? 'Thou art That'. Dry philosophy is of no use. One must continually put into practice. Thank you

Comment: thank you for what?? and yoga means unity with ones true nature

Comment: yes yoga is unity with Self :) thank you for asking such good questions and reserructing this site :P.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I am not a Vedajna. In fact no one in this world except God Himself is a true Vedajna even if many claim or act as if they are:

> **In the entire world no one but Me actually understands the confidential purpose of Vedic knowledge**. Thus people do not know what the Vedas are actually prescribing in the ritualistic injunctions of karma-kāṇḍa, or what object is actually being indicated in the formulas of worship found in the upāsanā-kāṇḍa, or that which is elaborately discussed through various hypotheses in the jñāna-kāṇḍa section of the Vedas. [SB - 11.21.42]

But by the grace of God and my gurus I could know the essence of the scriptures and know enough to answer your question.

There are **only three paths** (*yogas*) of *karma*, *bhakti* and *jnana* for the spiritual advancement of a person:

> *yogās trayo mayā proktā nṝṇāṁ śreyo-vidhitsayā
>
>   jñānaṁ karma ca bhaktiś ca nopāyo ’nyo ’sti kutracit* [SB - 11.20.6]
>
> **Meaning**
>   The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: My dear Uddhava, because I desire that human beings may achieve perfection, I have presented three paths of advancement — the path of knowledge, the path of work and the path of devotion. Besides these three there is absolutely no other means of elevation.

So by following anyone as per one's ability one can eventually come to the realization of his identity with Brahman. The thing is, jiva has similarities with Brahman and essentially both are one. But due to ignorance *jiva* identifies himself with the body and all other material attributes without realizing his true self. This ignorance is *maya* and whenever this *maya* in the form of *avidya* is  is crossed the realization occurs.

So irrespective of the path followed if one acquires the right knowledge he realizes aham brahmasmi. This is where various philosophy and methods come into action.

- To destroy ignorance some suggest acquiring knowledge through self inquiry and repeated contemplation on the truth that the self is Brahman - this is the path of Jnana. So the Veda says this *atma* alone should be heard, seen and thought upon:

  > *ātmā vā are draṣṭavyaḥ śrotavyo mantavyo nididhyāsitavyo* [Brh. Up - 2.4.5]
  >   -Verily it is the Self alone that should be seen, heard, thought and pondered over.
- Some suggest ceasing the mental activity and fixing it upon God alone - this is the path of yoga/*dhyana* yoga constituting eight limbs of yama, niyama, etc. Even by practicing this one gains the knowledge of oneness of God:

  > *sarvabhūtasthamātmānaṃ sarvabhūtāni cātmani
  >
  >   īkṣate yogayuktātmā sarvatra samadarśanaḥ* [BG - 6.29]
  >
  > **Meaning**
  >   The yogi sees his own self in every being and sees every being in his own self. He sees everywhere the same.
- Some suggest practicing devotion of God and through his grace the devotee automatically gains knowledge without any inquiry, etc:

  > *teṣāṃ satatayuktānāṃ bhajatāṃ prītipūrvakam
  >
  >   dadāmi buddhiyogaṃ taṃ yena māmupayānti te* [BG - 10.10]
  >
  > **Meaning**
  >   To those who constantly practice devotion to Me with love, I give them the knowledge by which they come to Me

But because the nature and interest of people are different, different kinds of philosophies (*samkhya, mimansa, yoga, vaishesika,* etc.) and their corresponding paths have come into existence including atheistic ones:

> Thus, due to the great variety of desires and natures among human beings, there are many different theistic philosophies of life, which are handed down through tradition, custom and disciplic succession. There are other teachers who directly support atheistic viewpoints. [SB - 11.14.8]

And about these plethora of philosophies and practices that the Shiva Samhita talks about in those verses. It is the nature of all scriptures of a particular system to shun other systems and paths so that the seeker may not get bewildered by trying to follow different paths of opposite views. It doesn't mean other two paths are wrong or less important. But the warning is valid because apart from the accepted philosophy and systems there are also systems like Charvak which are faulty and wrong.

Just like Shiva Samhita being a yoga text encourages Yoga alone as the right path, Shrimad Bhagavatam being a Bhakti text encourages Bhakti alone as the surest path. Uddhav asks similar questions like you regarding what is the presecribed path of the Vedas. And Shri Krishna in response [clears his doubts](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/14) answering his questions one by one:

> Śrī Uddhava said: My dear Kṛṣṇa, the learned sages who explain Vedic literature recommend various processes for perfecting one’s life. Considering these varieties of viewpoint, my Lord, please tell me whether all these processes are equally important, or whether one of them is supreme. [SB - 11.14.1]
>
> The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: By the influence of time, the transcendental sound of Vedic knowledge was lost at the time of annihilation. Therefore, when the subsequent creation took place, I spoke the Vedic knowledge to Brahmā because I Myself am the religious principles enunciated in the Vedas. [SB - 11.14.3]
>
> O best among men, the intelligence of human beings is bewildered by My illusory potency, and thus, according to their own activities and whims, they speak in innumerable ways about what is actually good for people.[SB - 11.14.9]
>
> Some say that people will be happy by performing pious religious activities. Others say that happiness is attained through fame, sense gratification, truthfulness, self-control, peace, self-interest, political influence, opulence, renunciation, consumption, sacrifice, penance, charity, vows, regulated duties or strict disciplinary regulation. Each process has its proponents. [SB - 11.14.10 ]
>
> All the persons I have just mentioned obtain temporary fruits from their material work. Indeed, the meager and miserable situations they achieve bring future unhappiness and are based on ignorance. Even while enjoying the fruits of their work, such persons are filled with lamentation. [SB - 11.14.11]
>
> O learned Uddhava, those who fix their consciousness on Me, giving up all material desires, share with Me a happiness that cannot possibly be experienced by those engaged in sense gratification. [SB - 11.14.12]
>
> One who does not desire anything within this world, who has achieved peace by controlling his senses, whose consciousness is equal in all conditions and whose mind is completely satisfied in Me finds only happiness wherever he goes. [SB - 11.14.13]

(**Please read that complete conversation and also [this one](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/20)  and your doubts will be cleared**)

Philosophy is nothing but a set of ideas and theories that gives an idea about the object and ways of life. It is a theory that puts the questioning mind into rest. But a philosophy can also have a practical aspect to it without following which dry philosophy is of no use. For example, yoga school of thought enjoins the practice of the eight limbs of yoga. The system of Bhakti enjoins practice of chanting, singing, etc. Vedanta school of thought enjoins contemplation upon Brahman and so on. So most philosophies have practical aspects also which should be followed.

...and what about discipline? Well, discipline is the minimum thing that everyone should follow irrespective of whether one is spiritual or not. In the path of *jnana* it is mandatory to live a disciplined life. In the path of Bhakti it is mandatory to remember God always whether you are disciplined or not. But at the end of the day, discipline is the foremost requirement for any spiritual practice. **A disciplined life is a spiritual life, otherwise it's not.**

## Is there any mentioning/praising of yoga-marga/yogic path in vedas?

Yes, there are many Upanishads like Nadabindu, Tejobindu, Yogasikha, etc. that are classified as Yoga Upanishads. In them the path of yoga has been mentioned and praised.

Comment: okay but no comments on Shiva samhita verses??

Comment: @Creator Those verses are right, what would I say about them? They just encourage the path of yoga. I had read them many years back and felt the same way that astanga yoga alone is the true path. But later on came to know and realize other things.

Comment: yeah but I am.not saying that asthanga yoga is only supreme but I am saying it is the basis of every other practice beacuse it enforces discipline, do you agree and what Vedas say about disciplining yoursef before anyothet margas

Comment: @Creator Of course I agree with that. That is why I said "A disciplined life is a spiritual life". Without discipline one can not say that he is living a spiritual life. And the thing is that in the case of Yoga, discipline is utmost important, without it one cannot even proceed further. Discipline is the abc of the system of yoga.

Comment: I request to add the excrept of uddhava - krishna conversation.

Comment: @Creator Ok, added the excerpt. But you should read the complete conversation when you get time.

Comment: I read it but was lost in the 11 skanda then found it in the uddhav gita section. I like to read it in devnagri script thats why prefer devnagri here also

Comment: @@behappy- The thestic Yoga school is not acceptable neither to badharayana nor to the principle commentators on bramha sutras, viz Shankara, Ramanuja and Madhva. The astanga yoga which is practised in the modern is not the actual Yoga.

Comment: @Krishna Yes, because they were the proponent of a different school of thought altogether which is Vedanta. So how could they accept or praise an opponent system!

Comment: @@behappy- I would disagree with you that just because they were proponents of vedanta, they don't accept other school of thought. Anything that is against vedas, Upanishads, bramhasutras is not acceptable to a true vedantin. Though, Yoga school is accepted as thestic school it says Isvara is only nimitta karana and not Upadana karana. Also, the Hatha Yoga etc is more concentrated on body than on the actual Yoga. So, saying that principle bhasyakaras (Badarayana, Shankara, Ramanuja and Madhva) were biased is totally, wrong.

Comment: @Krishna No problem...it's totally fine. But I never say whether one system is right or wrong or whether one is biased or not. I meant, it is just natural that one would not accept another school of thought than his own irrespective of whether it's right or wrong. May be someone is right and someone is wrong, but I don't bother myself with that cause I am happy with the truth :)

Comment: @Krishna I know the Yoga school rejects the notion that Ishwara is the Upadana Karana (material cause), but where do Patanjali's Yoga Sutras mention that Ishwara is even the Nimitta Karana (efficient cause)?

Comment: @Keshav -the limited info i have is,   Patanjali yoga sutras mentions isvara who is described as free from all afflictions and karma. I have no info on whether patanjali considers Isvara as upadana karana or nimitta karana or both. But, Vedanta sutra says : etena yoga pratyuktaha. The info, i have is that, as interpreted by Ramanuja, is that the philosophical theories of yoga, which are similar to samkhya, stand refuted, as they are opposed to vedanta. But, that which is not opposed to vedanta such as sadhana etc are acceptable to Visistadvaitin.

Comment: @Keshav - In the book "Indian philosophical systems", the author refers to Swami Desikan's, work "Paramatabhanga", wherein sums up, by saying that the original founders of samkhya and Yoga school, i.e. Kapila muni and Hiranyagarbha, were not opposed to vedanta sutras. It is the later adherents of these schools who created a conflict with Vedanta in respect of tbe doctrines developed by them.

Comment: @Keshav - The author further says, that the same is implied by Mahabharata statement : "Bavaha purusa rajan sankhya yoga vicharinaha; naite icchanti purusham ekam, kurukulodvana", meaning : there were several adherants of Yoga and sankhya schools, who didnt like to admit to existence of One Supreme being. Hence whatever is opposed to vedanta is to be rejected and whatever conforms to vedanta theories to be accepted.

Comment: @Yogi how come you accepted this answer? there are no citation from the vedas !!

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Actually this was asked 2 years ago..now I disagree with yoga school and the answer. Thanks for pointing out, btw now I cannot delete this post as it has an answer with positive votes.

Comment: what you disagree?